# JSON to delphi class - how to using generated class

Tags: json, delphi, inner-classes

Using JSONtodelphiclass (thank You Petar Georgiev) I generated unit with declared classes. In code I have got:

```
TItemClass = class
private
  FErrors_data: TArray<TErrors_dataClass>;
```

How to assign values of one class to another class property?

EDIT: (I will try to clarify)

I have got procedure:

```
   procedure TForm6.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      test:unit7.TRootClass;
      test2:unit7.TErrors_dataClass;
      test3:unit7.TItemClass;
    begin
         test2:=unit7.TErrors_dataClass.Create;
         test2.artykul:='p';
         test2.code:='y';
                showmessage(test2.ToJsonString);
         test3:=unit7.TItemClass.Create;
         test3.errors:='ooo';
         test3.link_plik:='link';
         test3.errors_data[0].FromJsonString(test2.ToJsonString);    <<<HERE
                showmessage(test3.ToJsonString);    
    end;
```

Which procedure I am trying to assign values 'test2'(TArray to 'test3.errors_data[0]'. When I am trying to assign values compiler shows AV (00000000) like in trying to assign to non created object. And I don't have any idea what is wrong

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to assign values of one class to another class property? For ex. class TRootClass property Items  should be tarray<TItemClass>, and I don't have any idea how

Comment: Please can you edit the question so that you make it very clear the precise question that you are asking.

Comment: To assign things, use the assignment operator, `:=`. If your question is more complicated than that, then consider posting some code demonstrating what you have, what you'd like to assign, and the error message you get when you attempt it.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be you forgot to create the RootClass that will answer your exception?
JSONtodelphiclass normally to my understanding will give you a unit containing one or more classes but it will contain also a TRootclass (If you haven't renamed it to something other.)

If you look into the constructor of TRootclass you will see that all other classes will be automatically created for you (and freed in destructor of TRootclass)

So all you have to do is:

```
var Test : TRootclass;
begin
  Test := TRootclass.create;
```

Now you should be able to access your other classes from Test without creating them again as you did.